# Big commerce cart is not updating quantity on desktop but working fine on mobile

Tags: javascript, bigcommerce

```js
<script>


    $(".mobile .qtyInput").change(function(){
    $(".desktop .qtyInput").val( $(this).val() );
    });
        $(".desktop .qtyInput").change(function(){
    $(".mobile .qtyInput").val( $(this).val() );
    });
</script>
```

Hi i am working on a big commerce cms,The problem i am facing is everytime i try to update the quantity of one product in my cart the other quantity of product also get updated,Its working fine on mobile,But on desktop it is giving me problem its updating the quantity of other products also automatically,Thank you in advance

```js
<tr class="desktop">
    <td class="CartThumb" style="%%GLOBAL_HideThumbColumn%%">
        %%GLOBAL_ProductImage%%&nbsp;
    </td>
    <td class="ProductName" colspan="%%GLOBAL_ProductNameSpan%%">
        <a href="%%GLOBAL_ProductLink%%">%%GLOBAL_ProductName%%</a>%%GLOBAL_ProductOptions%%
        <br>
        %%GLOBAL_ProductAvailability%%
        <div class="CartExpectedReleaseDate" style="%%GLOBAL_HideExpectedReleaseDate%%">(%%GLOBAL_ProductExpectedReleaseDate%%)</div>
        %%GLOBAL_EventDate%%
        <div style="%%GLOBAL_HideWrappingOptions%%" class="WrappingOptions">
            %%LNG_GiftWrapping%%:
            %%GLOBAL_GiftWrappingName%%
            <a href="#" onclick="Cart.ManageGiftWrapping('%%GLOBAL_CartItemId%%');" style="%%GLOBAL_HideGiftWrappingAdd%%">%%LNG_Add%%</a>
            <span style="%%GLOBAL_HideGiftWrappingEdit%%">
                (<a href="#" onclick="Cart.ManageGiftWrapping('%%GLOBAL_CartItemId%%');">%%LNG_Change%%</a> %%LNG_Or%% <a href="cart.php?action=remove_giftwrapping&amp;item_id=%%GLOBAL_CartItemId%%" onclick="return Cart.RemoveGiftWrapping();">%%LNG_Remove%%</a>)
            </span>
            <br>
            <span style="%%GLOBAL_HideGiftMessagePreview%%">
                %%LNG_GiftMessage%%:
                %%GLOBAL_GiftMessagePreview%%
            </span>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td align="center" class="CartItemQuantity">
        %%GLOBAL_CartItemQty%%
        
    </td>
    <td align="center" class="CartItemIndividualPrice">
        %%GLOBAL_ProductPrice%%
    </td>
    <td align="right" class="CartItemTotalPrice"><em class="ProductPrice">%%GLOBAL_ProductTotal%%</em>                
    </td>         
</tr>
<tr class="mobile">
    <td colspan="6">
        <div class="MobileCartItemTop">
        <div style="%%GLOBAL_HideCartItemRemove%%">  
            <a href="cart.php?action=remove&amp;item=%%GLOBAL_CartItemId%%" onclick="Cart.RemoveItem('%%GLOBAL_CartItemId%%'); return false;" class="CartRemoveLink" title="%%LNG_Remove%%">&nbsp;</a>
        </div>
            <div class="MobileCartItemImage">
        %%GLOBAL_ProductImage%%&nbsp;
        </div>

        <a href="%%GLOBAL_ProductLink%%" class="ProductName">%%GLOBAL_ProductName%%</a>
            
        </div>
        <div class="MobileCartItemBottom">
            <div class="MobileCartItemBottomLeft">
          <div class="MobileCartItemIndividualPrice">
                <span>Price:</span>%%GLOBAL_ProductPrice%%
                    </div>   
        %%GLOBAL_ProductOptions%%
        %%GLOBAL_ProductAvailability%%
        <div class="CartExpectedReleaseDate" style="%%GLOBAL_HideExpectedReleaseDate%%">(%%GLOBAL_ProductExpectedReleaseDate%%)</div>
        %%GLOBAL_EventDate%%
        <div style="%%GLOBAL_HideWrappingOptions%%" class="WrappingOptions">
            %%LNG_GiftWrapping%%:
            %%GLOBAL_GiftWrappingName%%
            <a href="#" onclick="Cart.ManageGiftWrapping('%%GLOBAL_CartItemId%%');" style="%%GLOBAL_HideGiftWrappingAdd%%">%%LNG_Add%%</a>
            <span style="%%GLOBAL_HideGiftWrappingEdit%%">
                (<a href="#" onclick="Cart.ManageGiftWrapping('%%GLOBAL_CartItemId%%');">%%LNG_Change%%</a> %%LNG_Or%% <a href="cart.php?action=remove_giftwrapping&amp;item_id=%%GLOBAL_CartItemId%%" onclick="return Cart.RemoveGiftWrapping();">%%LNG_Remove%%</a>)
            </span>
            <br>
            <span style="%%GLOBAL_HideGiftMessagePreview%%">
                %%LNG_GiftMessage%%:
                %%GLOBAL_GiftMessagePreview%%
            </span>
            
        </div>
               
            </div>
        <div class="MobileCartItemBottomRight">
<em class="ProductPrice">%%GLOBAL_ProductTotal%%</em>      
        %%GLOBAL_CartItemQty%%
        

        
          
       
        </div>
        </div>
        
        
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Sharing html to debug javascript is like calling the police to extinguish fire..

Comment: This is my script<script>


    $(".mobile .qtyInput").change(function(){
    $(".desktop .qtyInput").val( $(this).val() );
    });
        $(".desktop .qtyInput").change(function(){
    $(".mobile .qtyInput").val( $(this).val() );
    });
</script>